# idiomatic ways to express that "I don't want to force you to do this, so please don't be nervous or feel presured"

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

If I ask a friend (or a professor asks a student or a boss asks an employee) to do something for me and I don't want to let him feel that I am forcing him to do so and I won't be upset if he fails to accomplish it, what should I say in order to make him feel less nervous or pressured?

Answer (score 1):

When A asks B to do something, particularly if B is under some duty to be responsive to A, any request, however tentative or gentle, may may be perceived as an order. It makes no difference what words are used. There is no formula guaranteeing that B will believe that a refusal will have no adverse consequences.

The best that A can do is to be very clear that it is a request that B can refuse without consequence. In an informal context, something like "If you can do X, I'd be very pleased, but there is absolutely no problem if you cannot do it" might work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an English expert but,

Let someone off the hook: To not hold someone responsible for something
( https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-idioms/ )

This should be what you want:

> I let you off the hook for the consequences but i would appreciate if you could 'do something'